# How to execute persistent command from vim to bash?

Tags: external-command

When in vim I try to execute a persistent command, ie `alias gh="history | grep -a cd"` it seems to work at first but then I go to shell and type `gh` it says `command not found`. Note : I'm in `tty` shell, I'd like this to work both in terminal emulator and tty.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [unix.se].

Comment: You can't set aliases in a parent shell.  That's a design limitation of UNIX system, not Vim.

Comment: If you want _any_ configuration in bash to be persistent, you must set it in either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: you can always manually source your alias file

Comment: @djmoch - that will not work on modern linuxes, POSIX 2008 forbid `alias` from affecting anything that is not a direct subshell.  I believe this a a good Vim question because of POSIX 2008

Answer (score 1):

According to POSIX 2008 a shell level `alias` shall not affect applications invoked by a shell (only explicit subshells).  Excerpt from `man alias`:

```
   An alias definition shall affect the current shell execution environment and the execution environments of the sub‐
   shells of the current shell. When used as specified by this volume of POSIX.1‐2008, the alias definition shall  not
   affect  the parent process of the current shell nor any utility environment invoked by the shell; see Section 2.12,
   Shell Execution Environment.
```

Therefore Vim will never be able to use a shell alias in a system compliant to POSIX 2008.  I'd solve this with a `cabbrev` as follows:

```
:cabbrev gh history \| grep -a cd
```

The pipe needs to be escaped because it is the Vim command separator.  Then doing:

```
:!gh
```

Will perform

```
:!history | grep -a cd
```